# After installing pip3 I can't found it

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I just install pip3 by tapping :

**sudo apt-get install python3-pip**

When I press **pip3 -V**  this is the result :

**-su: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with updating the package list:

```
sudo apt update
```

Installing pip3.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Verify the installation by checking the pip version.

```
pip3 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Check where is calling pip with:

```
$ which pip3
```